Missing template menu when press "Add a new configuration" in CMake Settings Editor (Gui)
Nothing happens when I press "Add new configuration" in CMake settings editor when working with a CMake project in Visual Studio 2019.
What I have tried is press the green cross button and nothing happens. Normally, a menu shows up and lets me choose MinGW, MSVC or Clang with debug or release.
In Tool -> Options... -> CMake -> General -> CMakeSettings.json Template Directory, there is a path pointing to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\VisualStudio\CMakeSettingsTemplates, but there is no folder named VisualStudio in Documents. I think I accidentally deleted this folder in the past.
How can I get back these templates without reinstalling Visual Studio?
